# JavaFX Eclipse Exception

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I'm trying to figure out this error that starts after I refactor name of the project.(I tried reinstall Eclipse, create new workspace etc.)
My code was working well before that. If code is needed I can edit it later. Thanks for all advices.

```
Exception in Application start method
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Unknown Source)
at time.Run.start(Run.java:34)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
... 12 more
```

Exception running application time.Run

Comment: The error is self-explanatory, no? It can't find the image in the path you have specified. So at least show the code where you load the image. Presumably either you hard-coded the image URL relative to the project location (which is, for reasons that are now apparent, a very bad idea), or the project didn't deploy the image when it was rebuilt.

Comment: That's the problem. I didn't realize that. Thanks.